# convert row to columns redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following table:

```
 grantor | grantee | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | privilege_type | is_grantable | with_hierarchy

 james   | james   | dev           | test         | rest       | SELECT         | NO           | NO
 james   | james   | dev           | test         | rest       | DELETE         | NO           | NO
 james   | james   | dev           | test         | rest       | INSERT         | NO           | NO
 james   | james   | dev           | test         | rest       | UPDATE         | NO           | NO
 james   | james   | dev           | test         | rest       | REFERENCES     | NO           | NO
 james   | james   | dev           | test         | rest       | RULE           | NO           | NO
 james   | james   | dev           | test         | rest       | TRIGGER        | NO           | NO
 james   | yondo   | dev           | test         | rest       | SELECT         | YES          | NO
 james   | yondo   | dev           | test         | rest       | INSERT         | YES          | NO
```

I want to generate table as:

```
 grantee | table_name |   select   |   insert   |   delete   | update     | references | rule       | trigger
james   | rest       | TRUE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE
yondo   | rest       | TRUE:TRUE | TRUE:TRUE | FALSE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE | TRUE:FALSE | FALSE:FALSE | FALSE:FALSE
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT grantee, table_name,
    CASE WHEN privilege_type = 'SELECT' AND is_grantable='YES' THEN 'TRUE:TRUE' 
        ELSE 'TRUE:FALSE' END as select, 
        CASE WHEN privilege_type = 'INSERT' AND is_grantable='YES' THEN 'TRUE:TRUE' 
        ELSE 'TRUE:FALSE' END as insert, 
        CASE WHEN privilege_type = 'DELETE' AND is_grantable='YES' THEN 'TRUE:TRUE' 
        ELSE 'TRUE:FALSE' END as delete
    FROM information_schema.table_privileges WHERE table_schema='test';
```

but not working. What will be solution

Comment: Are you trying to find the privileges assigned to a user on an object ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to output one row per `grantee` and `table_name`, you will need to `GROUP BY grantee, table_name`:

```
SELECT
  grantee,
  table_name,
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN privilege_type = 'SELECT' AND is_grantable='YES' THEN 1 END) > 1 THEN 'TRUE:TRUE' ELSE 'TRUE:FALSE' END as select, 
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN privilege_type = 'INSERT' AND is_grantable='YES' THEN 1 END) > 1 THEN 'TRUE:TRUE' ELSE 'TRUE:FALSE' END as insert, 
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN privilege_type = 'DELETE' AND is_grantable='YES' THEN 1 END) > 1 THEN 'TRUE:TRUE' ELSE 'TRUE:FALSE' END as delete
FROM information_schema.table_privileges
GROUP BY grantee, table_name
WHERE table_schema='test';
```

(I didn't test it, so no guarantee!)

The above is counting whether the desired condition exists, and is then generating a single value per column.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you are saying that missing rows will never generate `FALSE:FALSE` then you are correct. You can only query off data that is present. You cannot query off absent data. (You could do complex `NOT IN` logic, but that is rarely a good idea.)

Comment: I have made changes  in question how to use NOT IN

Comment: tried this SELECT grantee, table_name, CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN privilege_type = 'SELECT' AND is_grantable='NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'TRUE:TRUE' ELSE 'TRUE:FALSE' END) = 0 THEN 'FALSE:FALSE' END as select, 
FROM information_schema.table_privileges  WHERE table_schema='test' GROUP BY grantee, table_name; getting empty result for select,in sert,delete,update column